# What are the rate limits for creating subscriptions?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am hitting the subscription rate limit, but I cannot find any further information regarding the limits.

```
Failed to create channel
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 OK
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Rate limit exceeded for creating file subscriptions",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "Rate limit exceeded for creating file subscriptions"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in your apis console.  You can find the Quota's for each API that you have enabled there.

For google drive mine shows:
10.0 requests/second/user
10,000,000 requests/day

Comment: This might be correct, but probably isn't. There are a number of unpublished rate limits and I suspect the OP is hitting one of those.